# What is the difference between creating a volume in docker-compose and in docker file?

Tags: docker-compose

I discovered docker-compose a few days ago.
I saw that it has a neat way to create volumes for serveral containers without any problems.

However, as far as I know it is possible to do the same in the respective docker files which produced each image. 
What are the advantages of creating the volumes in the docker-compose.yml and eventually its disadvantages?

Are they also any functional differences or are the outcomes the same?